# slickgrid highlight all edited cells

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slickgrid

I have a simple slickgrid table with two cols, *name* and *value*, where *value* is editable.
Now I want to highlight all changed values. For doing this I installed an *onCellChange()* handler, which adds a class *modified* to the currently modified cell. Unfortunately my code adds the class to the currently edited cell, but removes it from previously edited cells.

Here's part of the code

```
fieldView=new Slick.Data.DataView();
fieldView.setItems(rowData);
fieldView.reSort();
fieldGrid=new Slick.Grid(("#recordGrid"), fieldView, fieldColumns, editGridOptions);
fieldGrid.onCellChange.subscribe(function(e,args) {
    var modifiedCells={};
    modifiedCells[args.row] = {"value": "modified"};
    this.setCellCssStyles("modified", modifiedCells);
});
```

As said before this code only adds the 'modified' class to the last edited cell, but removes it from the previously edited cells. If I make *modifiedCells* global, only the first edited cell gets the 'modified' class.

What am I doing wrong? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid), but i think the problem is on the `key` arg you passed to the [`setCellCssStyles(key, hash)`](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#wiki-setCellCssStyles). As described in the documentation :

> <kbd>key</kbd> - A string key. Will overwrite any data already associated with this key.
>
> `setCellCssStyles(key, hash)` : Sets CSS classes to specific grid cells by calling `removeCellCssStyles(key)` followed by `addCellCssStyles(key, hash)`. key is name for this set of styles so you can reference it later - to modify it or remove it, for example. hash is a per-row-index, per-column-name nested hash of CSS classes to apply.

Because your `key` is always the same, the call to `removeCellCssStyles(key)` removes your previous edition information. You could make this `key` unique based on the row and cell index :

```
this.setCellCssStyles("modified." + args.row + "." + args.cell, modifiedCells);
```

As said i never used SlickGrid, so there might be a better solution but this one seems to work ;)